# Reasoning over functions applied to lists of nat in Coq

Tags: list, coq, proof, reasoning

We are working on verifying a system with three functions that looks like the following. However, we do not know how to proceed further with proofs like this. Actual definitions of the Coq functions may be shared. Kindly guide us.

```
Parameter weights : nat -> list nat -> nat -> nat.
Parameter schedule: nat -> list nat -> list nat. 
Parameter count: nat -> list nat -> nat.

Lemma high_weight_jobs: forall (s1 s2 jobs: nat) (S: list nat), 
  jobs > 0 ->
  length S > 0 ->
  weights s1 S 0 > weights s2 S 0 -> 
  count s1 (schedule jobs S) > count s2 (schedule jobs S).
Proof.
 intros.
 induction S as [ | h tl IHS].
 + simpl in *. inversion H0.
 + 
 Admitted.
```

Comment: Your theorem's conclusion does not follow from the premises that you have given. You must add more info about the functions.  Also, please don't use capital S to denote a `list nat`, it makes the code harder to read as S by convention stands for a constructor of nat.

Comment: @larsr given that function 'schedule' is using 'weights', I don't think more hypothesis are needed. Kindly share if you know a counter example that suggest adding more information or hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

You should start with thinking about what properties of these 3 functions you would need to prove this. It is usually not a good idea to proof a combined property of 3 functions based on the definitions of these 3 functions. First you prove properties of the 3 individual functions and then you prove the combined property based on these individual function properties.

You can first state such properties as axioms and see if they are indeed sufficient to prove what you want and then prove them later. I find this approach sometimes more efficient because I sometimes reformulate statements so that they are more convenient in the proof.

I also commonly use modules to abstract the definitions of functions and just use the specified properties of the functions to prove derived properties. This way you can abstract such properties from the actual implementation of the functions. This is helpful if you later need to extend one of the functions in some way. If all the properties still hold, derived proofs wouldn't be affected. If you do proofs based on the definitions, any such proof would very likely break with a change of the function.

For a further discussion, I suggest that you state the specification/properties of the 3 functions you think you need to prove this.

Comment: @M Soegtrop  You are right, that would be the right approach. Can you please suggest, few axillary but simple to prove lemmas that would enable us to prove the main lemma?

Comment: There is no way to answer this without knowing what your functions are supposed to do. Maybe you can start with a plain English description of what your functions should do.

Comment: P.S.: above youe asked for a counter example: count can be the function which always returns zero. Then your lemma obviosuly does not hold.

Comment: @M Soegtrop   In our definitions, when `count` gives 0, the function `weights` also returns 0, so we would be able to close that case by inversion on the hypothesis `weights s1 S 0 > weights s2 S 0 -> `.

Comment: It doesn't help a lot to give conditions with which you can proof one counter example wrong. You need to state the conditions which allow you to prove your statement. If this helps you, think of a counter example, which fulfills above condition, but still does not fulfill your statement. Then think of what condition you need to make this counter example wrong. Iterate that until you can't find any counter examples any more. Then we might be able to discuss a proof.

Comment: @Soegtrop   Thats right. The current theorem has been setup exactly the way you have proposed above. The theorem is provable, in our opinion, but how to prove it with Coq, we are stuck in that. We would appreciate guidance in how to proceed with it or add another axillary lemma to prove and then apply it here. May be kindly share your email and we will share the Coq script.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. Again: your theorem is not provable from the information you gave above - this is obvious because I gave a counter example. So first you need to have sufficient information about your function - and with this I mean written down in Coq and not in your head. When you give this information, we can discuss a proof. Otherwise what you ask for is impossible. Also how to prove this depends on the structure of this information. We can't guess how a proof would look like without this information.

Comment: @Soegtrop Once again thank you for your reply. May be you would be able to help more after looking at the actual script. Here is the Coq script.  Please share your advise to wilayatk@gmail.com, if any. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W8BqqZGbOsP6Scd2vzaErAv5XyQQCOvf/view

Comment: @Khan: a quick hint, which might get you going: In your file do a `Search (list ?T -> ?T -> nat) "count"`. This will show you that the standard library already has your count function - it is called `count_occ`. Then do a `Search (count_occ).` It will show you the kind of lemmas one proves about such functions. Before you do your final proof, you should think for every involved function what you can prove about it, similar to what the standard library proves about `count_occ`. Without this your proof might get hard. I didn't look at it in detail but this is how one approaches such a proof.

Comment: @Soegtrop Thanks once again for your valuable comments. We just replaced our "count" function with "count_occ" as you suggested. This is indeed good practice to replace a function with a standard one as it will enable us to use/apply the lemmas already proved for them. Unfortunately, with our poor Coq skills, we could not proceed further. Here is the updated Coq script: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ME9SWh-s6vzFCL92-Xrc7ojCCWXRiXza/view?usp=sharing.